# covariant virtual function in C++

Tags: c++

I tried following program, but compiler shows error.

```
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
    public:
        virtual Base& fun() const 
        {
            std::cout<<"fun() in Base\n";
            return *this;
        }
};
class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
         Derived& fun() const
        {
            std::cout<<"fun() in Derived\n";
            return *this;
        }
};
int main()
{
    Base* p=new Derived();
    p->fun();
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler errors:

```
[Error] invalid initialization of reference of type 'Base&' from expression of type 'const Base'
[Error] invalid initialization of reference of type 'Derived&' from expression of type 'const Derived'
```

Why I am getting these errors?
  But when I write following in both class' function program works fine.

```
return (Base&)*this;      // write this line in Base class function
return (Derived&)*this    // write this line in Derived class function
```

What is the meaning of above 2 statements?
  Please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **Solution:**

In your `fun` member functions (i.e., for both `Base::fun` and `Derived::fun`) you have to either drop the `const` qualifier of the function:

```
virtual Base& fun() 
{
  std::cout<<"fun() in Base\n";
  return *this;
}
```

or return a const reference to a `Base` class object.

```
virtual const Base& fun() const
{
  std::cout<<"fun() in Base\n";
  return *this;
}
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f879903c3538be80)

Also you have to define a virtual destructor at least for your `Base` class to ensure that destructors are evoked in the correct order.

### Explanation:

According to the standard *§ 9.3.2 The `this` pointer [class.this]*:

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword `this` is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of `this` in a member function of a `class X` is `X*`. **If the member function is declared `const`, the type of `this` is `const X*`,** if the member
>   function is declared `volatile`, the type of `this` is `volatile X*`, and if the member function is declared `const volatile`, the type of `this` is `const volatile X*`. [ Note: **thus in a `const` member function, the object for which the function is called is accessed through a `const` access path.** — end note ]

Thus, interpreting the above, in a `const` member function `this` is `const` so returning it as non-const reference drops its `const` qualifier and therefore the compiler rightfully complains.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf
Is this document are you referring? or more updated version is available for C++?
+1 for great explanation

Answer (score 4):

The `const` keyword in

```
virtual Base& fun() const
```

...makes `this` into a pointer to a `const` object inside the method. The problem is that you're trying to use

```
return *this;
```

...and return it from the method which returns `Base&`, thus dropping the `const`.

Either you need to drop the `const` in your declaration, making `this` not point to a const object, or you need to declare the method to return `const Base&`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `const` in a variable declaration, or on the return type of a function, it means "this value is read-only, so nobody is allowed to change it".  When you write `const` on one of the parameters in a function declaration, it means "this function is not going to change this value".  When you write `const` at the end of a member function (method) declaration, it means "this member function is not going to change the object on which it was called".

One of the compiler's jobs is to make sure that these `const` declarations are respected.  In particular, the compiler won't let you do any of the following.

- Change the value of a variable that's been declared as `const`.
- Change the value of an argument to a function, if the parameter was declared as `const`.
- Pass the value of a variable that's been declared as `const` into a function, by reference or by pointer, as a parameter that was NOT declared as `const`.
- Call a member function without the final `const` declaration on a variable that has been declared as `const`.

The reason for the third restriction is that if a function has been declared *without* the `const` declaration on one of its parameters, then the compiler won't prevent it from changing the value of the corresponding argument.  And if you could pass in a `const` variable to such a function, then the compiler would not be able to guarantee that its value won't change.  Therefore, the compiler won't let you pass in a `const` variable.

The reason for the fourth restriction is that if a member function has been declared *without* the `const` declaration at the end, then the compiler won't prevent it from changing the value of the object on which it was called.  And if you could call such a function on a `const` object, then the compiler would not be able to guarantee that its value won't change.

So if you ever write a function that *doesn't* change the value referenced by one of its arguments, (via a reference parameter or pointer parameter), then it's best to add the `const` into the declaration.  That way, it will be possible to call the function, passing in a `const` variable by reference or by pointer.  Likewise, if your member function doesn't change the value of the object on which it's called, then it's best to add the `const` at the end of the declaration.

But in your particular example, you have placed the `const` declaration at the end of a member function that returns a reference to the object on which it was called, but without having the `const` declaration on the returned reference.  That means that it would be possible to call this member function on a `const` object, assign the result to a non-`const` variable, then change its value via that variable.  This breaks the `const` rules.

To make this work, you have three options.

- Make the function return a value rather than a reference.
- Make the function return a `const` reference (that is, add the word `const` at the beginning of the function declaration).
- Remove the `const` declaration from the end of the function declaration.